# blank background in .png image converted to black, white, and other colors

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have this image:

empty plate

[image]

Using cv2 and the command

```
test = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("file_name.PNG"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

I read it in, and I get the following:

distorted empty plate

[image]

Similarly, I have this image:

blob on a plate

[image]

And after I use the same command as above to read it in, I get this:

distorted blob on a plate

[image]

When I omit the `cv2.cvtColor` and `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB`, I get a similar result, just with slightly different colors.

Can anyone advise as to what is going? I feel like it has something to do with the blank background, but I'm not sure.

Comment: try this :  `cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("file_name.PNG",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED),cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)`

Comment: @taront worked like a charm, thanks so much!